# Two subscripts for one item - not subscript of subscript

Tags: subscripts

Here a screenshot from a document my prof provided us with:
[image]

As you see, the last a_{ij} has two separate subscripts (i=1,...,m and j=1,...,n) and I cannot figure out how to do that. I only find how to give a subscript a subscript.

Can anyone help me out? Hopefully it's possible with only the ams math package. I am trying to add it to my Obsidian notes and as far as I know, I cannot add more packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

substack is your friend here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
(a_{ij})_{\substack{i=1,\ldots,m\\j=1,\ldots,n}}
\]
\end{document}
```